# Searching for images using instance_id instead bearer token in sentinel-hub service

Tags: sentinel-hub

When searching for images in sentinel-hub, can I search for images (in browser address line) using INSTANCE_ID instead bearer token (acquired after authentication)?

I'm asking it aiming avoid various requests to the SHub service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Sentinel Hub [WFS service](https://www.sentinel-hub.com/develop/api/ogc/standard-parameters/wfs/), which uses instance ID, rather than authentication token.
That said, you will have to have a Sentinel Hub account (and subscription) to use this service.